# Centering column in mathmode

Tags: equations, labels, alignment, tag

This minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        f(x) & = &\displaystyle\int_0^1 f'(x) d x  \\[.2cm]
        e^{i\pi} +1 &= & 0
    \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produces the following result
[image]

I would like the tag to refer to the first equation, keeping the horizontal alignment in each column. Is there a way to do it automatically without setting the space for each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `align` environment, in conjunction with `\notag`.  It provides better math spacing than `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
        f(x) &= \displaystyle\int_0^1 f'(x) d x  \\[.2cm]
        e^{i\pi} +1 &= 0 \notag
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to use the `array` environment, top align it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}[t]{ccc}
        f(x) & = &\displaystyle\int_0^1 f'(x) d x  \\[.2cm]
        e^{i\pi} +1 &= & 0
    \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I usually use the `align` environment, but I want that horizontal alignment. I used the `article` class, but actually, the code is for a presentation that requires each term to be centred.

Comment: @LucaBenatti See my edit.  You can top-align the array.

Comment: Okay, this fits in this case since the equation to be tagged is the first. But if I would have five equations and I have to refer to the second one? Maybe it is off-topic, I'll open a different question for that.